# Does nvarchar(max) in SQL Server cause any perfomance overhead while inserting data into database?

Tags: sql-server, database

I was using `nvarchar(300)` earlier in my SQL Server.

I was setting the attribute on the entity like this:

```
@Column(name="stud_desc" length= 300)
private String studentDescription;
```

Now because of some reasons, I have to remove the `length=300` validation part and I set the column in the database to `nvarchar(max)`.

Now while inserting data into the table, I have noticed that the insert query takes a little bit more time.

Although most of the character length is < 1k, some are also over 8k.

My question is: does using the above column datatype in SQL Server have any performance impact?

Also what would be the safer alternative? ( if anything)

Answer (score 0):

yes, the server engine will begin to prepare to dedicate resources based on the potential bit length parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Even Though You do not fill in the values to the maximum, due to the way SQL Server stores and pages data, it makes sure to dedicate the amount of space needed based on what's defined in the structure.

The alternative for this might be a dedicated 1:(0..1) relationship table, where You have the StudentID and Description. Thus, if the Description is not needed, it might be faster. Otherwise, it's all about managing data.

Comment: if the number of character is mostly < 250 and vary rare time it does equivalent to max length ..does this scenario also sql server ta cause performance hit as always sql server need to create room for max length?